# Making Eclipse play well with JPMS and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-module

Given a Maven project created in Eclipse from archetype *maven-archetype-quickstart* ( with junit upgraded to 5.5.2, which has JPMS support) , how can it be modularized to a JPMS project and still behave well in Eclipse?

When I tried this, I first created the module folder in the `java` folder and moved the package structure into that. The project structure then looks like this:

> jpms (project folder) -> src/main/java/**org.myorg.mymodule**/org/myorg/myproject/jpmspackage

. So far so good. The project builds with `mvn clean install` in console and the unit test is executed. Then the module folder (containing the module-info.java file + packages) was set to source folder ("use as source folder" in Eclipse).

Performing a Maven build in Eclipse now fails with

> Cannot nest'jpms/src/main/java/org.myorg.mymodule' inside 'jpms/src/main/java'. To enable the nesting exclude 'org.myorg.mymodule/' from 'jpms/src/main/java'

**How can the source folder or build path be set to appease Eclipse?**

Module descriptor:

```
module org.myorg.mymodule {
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
}
```

Updated JUnit dependency (the project was originally generated with JUnit 3-something)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Versions: Eclipse 2019-09, Java 12, Maven 3.6.2

Comment: Do not change the project structure, just add the `module-info.java` file into the default package (e.g. by right-clicking the project folder and choosing _Configure > Create module-info.java_). Please note, that for each module a separate project is required as it does not make sense to have multiple modules (which have different dependencies) in one project (if required, use nested projects instead).

Comment: That would satisfy the stated problem, but can the module be compiled with `javac <magic arguments> --module org.myorg.mymodule` without a separate module folder? Eg the above examble compiles with `javac -d target/classes/ --module-source-path src/main/java/ --module-path libs/  --module org.myorg.mymodule` (if I cheat and put required jars in the libs).  Without a module folder, it seems javac can't find the module.

Comment: A project structure with source and output folders on the first level and folders for the modules on a deeper level contradicts several years of best practice (modularization is all about encapsulation). Better use an example with a best practice project structure, e.g. [like this one](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module-project-java-jpms) (which I guess will work also in Eclipse without adaptions).

Comment: If you make an answer of your first comment I'll mark it as accepted since it solves the problem as stated (adding a folder was not an prerequisite I just assumed it was needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the project structure, just **add the `module-info.java` file into the default package**:

1. **Right-click the project folder** and choose ***Configure > Create module-info.java***

Please note, that for each module a separate project is required as it does not make sense to have multiple modules (which have different dependencies) in one project (if required, use nested projects instead).

See also this [Java modules Maven example](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module-project-java-jpms).